# Question on the DDD approach to assessing the impact of COVID-19 on students

Tags: difference-in-difference

My goal is to evaluate the evolution of the COVID-19 effect using a triple difference estimator

First, I am using a differences-in-differences model to evaluate the effect of COVID-19 on student test scores. I am interested in the progression of students between grade 2 and grade 5 for a cohort exposed to COVID-19 in grade 5 (but not in grade 2) and a cohort not exposed to COVID-19 (neither in grade 2 nor grade 5). Following the methodology used by [Engzel et al. (2021)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eLmn.png) (page 8 in the [article's appendix](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.euroecorev.2023.104405)), I estimate the progression of students between grade 2 and grade 5 using the following equation:

$$
\Delta y_{i,g} = \alpha + \mathbf{X_i}' \beta + \delta T_{i,g} + \Theta_r + \Gamma_s + \epsilon_{i,s}
$$

Where $X_i$ is a set of covariates, $T_{i,g}$ is an indicator for treatment for individual $i$ in group $g$, $\Theta_r$ is a fixed effect at the regional level, and $\mathrm{I}_s$ is a fixed effect at the school level. $\epsilon{i,s}$ is the error term clustered at the school level. $G$ is indicator for the group (which will then be used as the source of the third difference). I estimate this equation for each group $g$.

[After trying it on my data, estimating this equation is equivalent to estimating a panel differences-in-differences equation (such as [Battisti and Maggio, 2023](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.euroecorev.2023.104405)) in the form: $ Score = \alpha +  \mathbf{X_i}' \beta + \gamma t_{i,g} + \delta T_{i,g} + \zeta T_{i,g} t_{i,g} + \Theta_r + \Gamma_s + \epsilon_{i,s} $]

I have two cohorts of students (groups $g$) enrolled in grade 5 after COVID-19, the first in 2020/21 and the second in 2021/22, by conducting an initial differences-in-differences estimation (see the attached table) for the cohort enrolled in grade 2 in 2017/18 and grade 5 in 2020/21 (with a control group enrolled in grade 2 in 2014/15 and grade 5 in 2017/18), and a second differences-in-differences estimation for the cohort enrolled in grade 2 in 2018/19 and grade 5 in 2021/22 (with a control group enrolled in grade 2 in 2015/16 and grade 5 in 2018/19), I can then assess the evolution of the COVID-19 effect between the two cohorts (the one enrolled in grade 5 in 2020/21 and the one enrolled in grade 5 in 2021/22) using a triple difference estimator (the results of my triple difference estimate correspond to the difference between my estimates in difference-in-differences for group 1 and group 0).

[image: Table]

While my estimates are consistent, I have questions about how to formally write the equation for my estimate in triple differences. Does anyone have any ideas how to write this equation? Does my formulation seem correct to you? This is how I have written it:

$$
\Delta y_{i,1} - \Delta y_{i,0} = \alpha + \mathbf{X_i}' \beta + \mathbf{X_i}' \gamma G_i + \delta T_{i} + \zeta G_i + \eta T_{i} G_i + \Theta_r + \Gamma_s + \epsilon_{i,s}
$$